# Concatenate string to data frame column

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to append to a data.frame the same string.

```
> df1 <- data.frame(pt1="a", pt2="b", row.names=1)
> df1
  pt1 pt2
1   a   b
```

As a result I would like to have:

```
   pt1                 pt2
1  Add this string a   Add this string b
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `lapply`

```
df1[] <- lapply(df1, function(x) paste('Add this string', x))
```

Or use `Map`

```
df1[] <- Map(paste, 'Add this string', df1)
```

Or

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
     mutate_each(funs(paste('Add this string', .)))
```